# Let $f \in C([-1, 1])$ and differentiable on $(-1, 1)$, such that $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\,dx = 1$. Prove $\exists c \in (-1, 1)$ such that $f'(c)\geq1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that it is differentiable on $(-1, 1)$ and satisfies $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\, dx = 1$. Prove there exists $c \in (-1, 1)$ such that $f'(c) \geq 1$.

This is what I've attempted so far:

We can define a function $g(x): [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = f(x) - x$. As a composition of continuous and differentiable functions it is also continuous and differentiable on appropriate intervals.

$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\, dx = 1$, by Newton-Leibniz formula we have  $\phi(1) - \phi(-1) = 1$, where $\phi'(x) = f(x)$.

Taking the derivative of both sides yields $\phi'(1)-\phi'(-1) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(1) = f(-1)$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$, differentiable on $(-1, 1)$ and $f(-1) = f(1)$, by Rolle's theorem there exists $\xi$ such that $f'(\xi) = 0$.

For that $\xi$, $g'(\xi) = f'(\xi) - 1 = -1$.

Now this is where I got stuck. I can't think of a single direction to take other than the ones I've taken, and they've gotten me nowhere. I've also tried using the fact the area under the function f is positive, but it hasn't helped either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac 12$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and  $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=1$. However $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$, so the conclusion is false.

Comment: I suspect there was an additional condition on $f$ that the proposer overlooked.